# how to use react-highlight-words to highlight multiple keywords with different colors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, full-text-search, highlight

I am developing a search function in my React project.
In the beginning, I only need to input one keyword and search for it in the text, save the sentences with this keyword and display the result sentences separately. I am using "react-highlight-words" https://github.com/bvaughn/react-highlight-words to highlight this single keyword in all the search result sentences.

```
{searchResults.map((result, idx) => {
      
      return (
        <div key={`search-result-${idx}`}>
            <br />
            <Highlighter
              highlightClassName='YourHighlightClass'
              searchWords={[textForSearch]}
              autoEscape={true}
              textToHighlight={finalResults[idx]}
              key={idx}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    })}
```

above `textForSearch` is the keyword `finalResults` is the search result.
I use a keyword to loop through the text and save the match sentences as elements to an array.

But now I need to input multiple keywords in one search and display some sentences or a paragraph containing these keywords and highlight different keywords with different colors.

how can I use this component to do it? and if some other way to do it please tell me.
I have seen many topics and answers related to search and highlight but they all highlight different words with the same color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const Highlight = ({ children, highlightIndex }) => (
    <span className={`highlighted-text keyword-${highlightword.indexOf(children)}`}>{children}</span>
);
```

and add tag -  highlightTag={Highlight}